# OVA like deployment of groups of servers on vSphere

Tags: vmware-vsphere

I am hoping there's an easy way to create something like an ova template for deploying a set of various vmware servers.  Ideally, this would allow, for example, a fully functional AD environment (composted of, again as an example, three routers, two AD machines, and two clients).

So far, my research hasn't revealed any techniques for doing this.  I could have ova templates for each, and then deploy them one by one, but a one-button sort of solution would be great.  Perhaps I'm not searching for the right terms to find the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a vApp containing all your appropriate VMs, including boot order and IP pool details and just export it as an .OVA.

Comment: Thanks.  That was the word I was apparently unable to come up with.